# How to get the exact index ID numbers of Maya ramp points using Maya python commands and not API

Tags: python, textures, maya

Is it possible to query the Index numbers of the points of a 2D graph texture in Maya using Maya commands and Python and not API code? The points do not necessarily start at 0 and are not always sequential. [image]

Comment: May I ask why not using the API?

Comment: I am still learning Python and fairly new to coding in general, so the API approach is daunting and likely above my head at this point.  I just have limited experience using it.

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
indices = cmds.getAttr("ramp1.colorEntryList", mi=True)
for i in indices:
    p=cmds.getAttr("ramp1.colorEntryList[" + str(i) + "].position")
    print(p)
    c=cmds.getAttr("ramp1.colorEntryList[" + str(i) + "].color")
    print(c)
```